# New line in BBcode editor

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bbcode

I am using BBcode editor to post something through form. When I make new line by pressing enter an then send form and printing sent text on screen everything is in one line and there are no BBcode representing it. At first I though it was something wrong with the editor I was using but after change the problem continues.

How can I make a new line?

```
<?php       
    $post=$_POST['editor'];     

    echo "$post;    


?>
```

Here is my php code. I just want to print sent text on screen

Comment: <br/> ..............

Comment: Plz post your back-end (PHP) code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New line characters, whether in BBcode or in form of console `\n` input are not "br /" line breaks in html. So if you are capturing input from html textbox using php then you have to convert the BBcode new line or console `\n` characters into its html equivalent `<br />`

Try using this:

```
$post=$_POST['editor'];
$post = nl2br($post);
echo $post;
```

You can also try using regex and then you can specify which characters you want converted into html line breaks.

```
$post=$_POST['editor'];
$post = preg_replace("/(\r\n|\n|\r)+/",   "<br />",    $post);
echo $post;
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work... I don't kow why though. I've read about nl2br just now and it should have helped

Comment: Try this:  print bin2hex($_POST['teditor']); exit; This will display hex encoded characters as you entered them. So don't type anything but only make new line by pressing enter an then send form and see what code will be printer out.

Comment: it printed nothing. But thanks to that I realized something. I was using this bbcode editor on input field. Now I changed it to textfield and it works. So much time wasted because of such simple mistake...